# Currently getting an error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<ipython-input-21-0cdf2cfacf71>", line 335, in <module>  
    + my_value_a  
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Can anyone help with this error?

Code

```
def get_env_var(i):
    try:
        letter = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'][i // 50]
        return os.getenv("MY_VAR_" + letter)
    except IndexError:
        return "demo"


for i in range(0, len(mySymbols)):
    try:
        my_value_a = get_env_var(i)
        #my_value_a = "demo"
        #my_value_a =  os.getenv("MY_VAR_K")
        url_is_y = (
            "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/"
            + mySymbols[i]
            + "?apikey="
            + my_value_a
        )
        url_bs_y = (
```

Comment: Please provide relevant piece of code which caused this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the key for `os.getenv()` is invalid, it returns the default values that you pass as the second parameter. If you don't set this default value, it returns a `None`.   Possible Fixes:

```
def get_env_var(i):
    try:
        letter = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'][i // 50]
        return os.getenv("MY_VAR_" + letter, "demo")
    except IndexError:
        return "demo"
```

This will return the "demo" string if an invalid key is encountered. Or you can do this if the output is acceptable:

```
for i in range(0, len(mySymbols)):
    try:
        my_value_a = get_env_var(i)
        #my_value_a = "demo"
        #my_value_a =  os.getenv("MY_VAR_K")
        url_is_y = (
            "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/"
            + mySymbols[i]
            + "?apikey="
            + str(my_value_a) # This will convert None to 'None'
        )
        url_bs_y = (
```

Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) page out for more info and examples on how this function works.

Comment: `os.environ[f"MY_VAR_{letter}"]` will raise a `KeyError` if the variable isn't found, letting you catch a `LookupError` (the base class of both `IndexError` and `KeyError`) in order to specify the default return value only once.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the latest URL:

```
"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/"
```

without the "financials" part in it.